# Rotation of layout changes the co-ordinate of the motion event

Tags: android, image-rotation, motionevent

i am cropping a image by the help of a child relative layout and i am moving  it by motion event over a parent  relative layout(containing image-view to be cropped).
..but when i rotate parent layout (in which i have the image view )  by 90 deg. the behavior of motion event co-ordinate changes,and does not work(drag and zoom of child layout)properly.. 
please somebody tell me how to fix this..i have done some research and found about the AXIS_ORIENTATION in motionevent class but did not get any example regarding to it.
thanks in advance :)