# MotionEvent.getX(int) does not work on onTouchEvent if the view is RotationY(90)

Tags: android, multi-touch

I'm testing multi-touch

I want to rotate the view with RotationY when the view is dragged.
In single touch, I solved it using getRawX.
However, I can not get getRawX (other pinters) values in multi-touch while the view is rotating.
So I used "MotionEvent.transForm (view.getMatrix ())".
This seemed to work.
However, in RotationY(90) there was a problem of coordinates.

[[Play Youtube]](https://youtu.be/AMCBI61O-Uc)

[Full source](https://github.com/muabe/TouchIssue)

```
   View single_touch, multi_touch;

float single_preX;
boolean isSingleStating = false;

float multi_preX1,multi_preX2;
boolean isMultiStating = false;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    single_touch = findViewById(R.id.single_touch);
    single_touch.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            switch(event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    if(isSingleStating){
                        float deltaX = event.getRawX() - single_preX;
                        single_touch.setRotationY(single_touch.getRotationY()+(int)(deltaX/3));
                    }
                    single_preX = event.getRawX();
                    isSingleStating = true;
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    single_preX = 0f;
                    isSingleStating = false;

            }
            return true;
        }
    });


    multi_touch = findViewById(R.id.multi_touch);
    multi_touch.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            switch(event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    if(event.getPointerCount()!=2){
                        return false;
                    }
                    event.transform(multi_touch.getMatrix());
                    if(isMultiStating){
                        float deltaX = ((event.getX(0) - multi_preX1) + (event.getX(1) - multi_preX2))/2f;
                        multi_touch.setRotationY(multi_touch.getRotationY()+(int)(deltaX/3));

                    }
                    multi_preX1 = event.getX(0);
                    multi_preX2 = event.getX(1);
                    isMultiStating = true;
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    multi_preX1 = 0f;
                    multi_preX2 = 0f;
                    isMultiStating = false;
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
}
```

Who can solve this problem?
Please contact me if you resolve this issue.
Email : markjmind@gmail.com

Comment: because it is pointless to `getX()` as it can have any value from `Float.NEGATIVE_INFINITY` to `Float.POSITIVE_INFINITY` meaning .... nothing

Comment: @오재웅, what you expect it to return?

Comment: @ azizbekian, @pskink (Modify Source)https://youtu.be/AMCBI61O-Uc 
I want to rotate the view with RotationY when the view is dragged.
In single touch, I solved it using getRawX.
However, I can not get getRawX (other pinters) values in multi-touch while the view is rotating.
So I used "MotionEvent.transForm (view.getMatrix ())".
This seemed to work.
However, in RotationY(90) there was a problem of coordinates.

Comment: so whats wrong with such a simple code: http://pastebin.com/s8ZUrkxM ?

Comment: Your sample gets a TouchEvent from the parent view. then rotates the child view.
I want the view that receives touchEvent to rotate.

Comment: I can not speak English very well.
So Even if I did not solve the problem, I was impressed with your efforts.
Thank you. Thank you

Comment: `FL` view "receives touchEvent to rotate" and rotates its child view

Comment: @pskink Please refer to here(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28766334/rotation-of-layout-changes-the-co-ordinate-of-the-motion-event) It is a similar my problem.